# Как создать кнопку в libgdx с помощью pack?

Tags: json, button, libgdx

**Я пытался создать кнопку в libgdx, но у меня возникла путаница с pack и json файл. В результате возникает ошибка при чтении json файла.**

**Мой код:**

```
stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    Skin skin = new Skin();
    TextureAtlas buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("buttons/buttons.atlas"));
    skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
    skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("skin.json"));

    TextButton button = new TextButton("Button1", skin, "default");
    stage.addActor(button);
    button.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            System.out.println("Click");
        }
    });
    button.setX(250);
    button.setY(250);
    button.setWidth(100);
    button.setHeight(100);
    stage.addActor(button);
```

**Это мой atlas, я создавал его через GDXTexturePacker**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Это мой json файл**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Итог libgdx очень запутанный**

Answer (score 1):

Думаю у вас какие-то проблемы в JSON файле, хотя не уверен какие именно. Вообщем это странно. Не понимаю зачем нужны все эти костыли с разными файлами в этом libgdx, неужели нельзя было сделать как в JavaFX.

Comment: А нельзя ли конкретнее объяснить в чём дело?

Answer (score 1):

Libgdx получился довольно костыльным, как я понимаю, просто смешны эти методы с dispose. В Java прямое управление памятью это вообще бросается в глаза. Мой совет не используйте этот огромный костыль. Лучше используйте, хотя бы lwjgl, где своими надстройками не испортили все.